# Export wordpress from OpenShift account

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

I have a blog hosted at openshift but would like to move it, I have wordpress installed using 1 small gear (not scalable).  I've tried plugins like WP Clone by WP Academy and Move Wordpress but the server times out before the backup/clone/zip file is created.

I was able to login to my openshift account using SFTP to manually copy the wordpress installation to the new server but the structure is different than what I'm used.

I would prefer to just use a plugin like WP Clone by WP Academy, how I can get it to work?

If not, where are the wordpress files on openshift so I can copy them to my new host?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are sorry to see you go, please email openshift@redhat.com if we can do anything to help you stay!

If you have to go, we understand though, here is a breakdown of the file locations (assuming you used our quickstart):

```
~/app-root/data/uploads (files uploaded through wordpress
~/app-root/data/themes (themes uploaded through wordpress)
~/app-root/data/plugins (plugins uploaded through wordpress)
~/app-root/data/blogs.dir (uploads and assets for wordpress multi-site installation)
~/app-root/repo/php (all other wordpress core files)
```

You can use mysqldump from the command line to get your wordpress database, all of the login information is there in the environment variables, and your database name is the same as your app name.

You can also use the `rhc snapshot save` command to get a complete backup of your application.

Let us know if you need any more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is instruction [how-to migrate from OpenShift](http://druss.info/2015/01/migrate-wordpress-site-from-openshift-to-vps/)

- Backup database
- Copy all files from server
- **Modify Wordpress config**
- Upload to a new server
- Restore database backup